# Не запускается Viber бот на Linux

Tags: python, viber

Я установил библиотеку viberbot с помощью pip

```
pip install viberbot
```

но при запуске ловлю

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from viberbot import Api
ImportError: No module named 'viberbot'
```

pip list:

```
Package      Version
------------ ---------
certifi      2020.11.8
chardet      3.0.4
click        7.1.2
Flask        1.1.2
future       0.18.2
idna         2.10
itsdangerous 1.1.0
Jinja2       2.11.2
MarkupSafe   1.1.1
pip          20.2.4
requests     2.24.0
six          1.15.0
urllib3      1.25.11
viberbot     1.0.11
virtualenv   15.1.0
Werkzeug     1.0.1
```

как решить проблему?

Comment: Как запускаете?

Comment: @andreymal так же как и телеграмм ботов, python3 bot.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что у вас на машине установлено две версии Python - 2 и 3.

Именно поэтому, при вызове `pip` он устанавливает библиотеки для второго питона. Так как вы используете третью версию, то используйте `pip3`.

То есть:

```
pip3 install viberbot
```